# Comunicar token firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, login

tengo un servicio web y una aplicación android, cuando inicio sesión con un user y pass en android lo compruebo en el servidor y este me devuelve un token , como puedo registrar este token en firebase? o que tengo que hacer para poder establecerlo al dispositivo y poder recibir notificaciones... Lo que me interesa es que el servidor genere el token y cada vez que inicie sesión algún dispositivo le genere uno.
Un saludo y gracias.

Comment: Hola @David. ¡Bienvenido a [es.So]! ¿Podrías acotar un poco la pregunta? Cómo está redactada, una respuesta necesitaría escribir todo el código en tu lugar para contestar. La idea es que puedas hacer una pregunta concreta mostrando el código con lo que intentaste y dónde está fallando. Quizás te sea útil realizar el [tour] y leer [ask]. Intenta publicar un [mcve]

Comment: Seguramente cerraran tu pregunta David, debes revisar lo que Mariano sugiere, por otro lado te comento que el token que obtienes tu lo tienes que guardar, no es necesario pedir uno cada vez que inicies la aplicación, ya que regularmente te da el mismo, el token se vuelve a pedir cuando haya caducado o no sea válido, revisa la implementación.  Revisa este tutorial de nuestros amigos de "Hermosa programación" http://www.hermosaprogramacion.com/2016/06/android-push-notifications-firebase-cloud-messaging/

Comment: Modifica tu pregunta y se puede volver a abrir ! saludos!.